# Rails - How to test validate_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have the following model that has custom validation for a valid code.

```
class MyAd < ApplicationRecord
  validates_with CodeValidator
end
```

and the following class:

```
class CodeValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    code = record.ad_code

    return if is_double_id?(code) || is_id?(code)

    if code.blank? || code == 'NO_CODE'
      record.errors[:base] << "A valid code is required."
    end
  end

  def is_double_id?(code)
    code.match(regex here)
  end

  def is_id?(code)
    code.match(regex here)
  end
end
```

How do I write a test for this? I am new to rails and have adopted this code so am a bit confused as to how to do it.

Here is what I started but from reading I am not sure how to test it. Does MyAd.new() force the validation to happen?

```
require 'test_helper'

class MyAd < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    @ad = MyAd.new(ad_code: 894578945)
  end

  test 'it test code validity' do
    #this is where i need help
  end
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `@ad.valid?` will run the validations

Answer (score 1):

Just setup a valid / invalid model instance and call `#valid?` to trigger the validations. You can then write assertions about the [errors object](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html).

```
require 'test_helper'

class MyAd < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'it does not allow a blank code' do
    @ad = MyAd.new(code: '')
    @ad.valid? # fires the validations
    # @fixme your validator should actually be adding errors to :ad_code and not :base 
    assert_includes(@ad.errors[:base], 'A valid code is required.')
  end

  test 'it allows a valid code' do
    @ad = MyAd.new(code: 'SOME VALID CODE')
    @ad.valid? 
    refute_includes(@ad.errors[:base], 'A valid code is required.')
  end
end
```

Don't test validations by:

```
# as popularized by the Rails tutorial book
assert(model.valid?)
refute(model.valid?)
```

This carpet bombing approach will test every validation on the model at once and your really just testing your test setup.

> Does MyAd.new() force the validation to happen?

No. Validations are performed when you call `#valid?` or the [persistence methods](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html) like `#save`, `.create` and `#update`.

Comment: The object under test needs some work. Don't add your errors to :base unless they are not related to any attribute. Create different meaningful error messages for blank/format etc.

Comment: Thanks very much! Worked a treat and thanks for explanation